# List and LazyVStack performance and reusability

Tags: swiftui

I'm benchmarking performances between using `List`, `ScrollView` and `LazyVStack` and found something strange (at least for me) between those two implementations:

```swift
/// Case 1: `LazyVStack` if wrapping `ForEach`
var body: some View {
    List {
        LazyVStack {
            ForEach(data) { data in
                AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/200/300"))
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
/// Case 2: `ForEach` is wrapping `LazyVStack`
var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(data) { data in
            LazyVStack {
                AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/200/300"))
                    .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd expect case 1 to be the more logic implementation **but actually case 2 performs better**.

**Case 1** doesn't unload images from memory and the memory keeps going up as I scroll.

**Case 2** unloads images from memory as I scroll down. But doesn't this implementation creates a new LazyVStack for each row?

Can someone help me understand why would Case 2 perform better in that case?

Thanks.

Comment: What about case 3, `List` with `ForEach`? Lists are lazy already.

Comment: There's no reason to ever have both List and LazyVStack. Use one or the other. Both components are lazy, so by combining them, you just mess up their caching strategy without any added benefit.

Answer (score 5):

`List` lazy loads views, but also has a view re-use mechanism. `LazyVStack` lazy loads views, but doesn't have a re-use mechanism, so it will keep everything as it grows.

In example one, you are not using `List`'s reuse mechanism because there is only one `LazyVStack` inside it. The lazy stack will start off small and keep growing as you scroll, and the list will be unaware of this, because it only contains a single view.

In example 2, the list knows how to deal with a `ForEach`, and can reuse the views as you scroll. You're creating a new (pointless) `LazyVStack` for each row but it isn't really doing anything, since it only ever contains a single view. You can just write it as a `ForEach` containing the async image.

However...

If you have a collection of identifiable types, and you want a list of them (no dynamic actions like deleting rows on swipe or moving items), you don't even need a `ForEach`:

```swift
/// Case 4: Just a `List`
var body: some View {
    List(data) { data in
        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/200/300"))
            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
    }
}
```

Comment: so, what about if I want a grid inside List, what is the better way to do this re-use mechanism

Comment: Grid is neither lazy nor re-using, so you would be relying on List to manage a set of individual grids.