UIKit in SwiftUI memory leak while displaying images
I'm using UIKit to display a long list of large images inside a SwiftUI ScrollView and LazyHStack using UIViewControllerRepresentable. When an image is loaded, I'm using SDWebImage to load the image from the disk.
As the user navigates through the list and continues to load more images, more memory is used and is never cleared, even as the images are unloaded by the LazyHStack. Eventually, the app reaches the memory limit and crashes. This issue persists if I load the image with UIImage(contentsOfFile: ...) instead of SDWebImage.
How can I free the memory used by UIImage when the view is removed?
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
    LazyHStack(spacing: 16) {
        ForEach(allItems) { item in
            TestImageDisplayRepresentable(item: item)
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                .id(item.id)
        }
    }
    .scrollTargetLayout()
}

import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import SDWebImage

class TestImageDisplay: UIViewController {
    
    var item: TestItem
    
    init(item: TestItem) {
        self.item = item
        
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
        imageView.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        
        imageView.sd_setImage(with: item.imageURL, placeholder: nil)
    }
}

struct TestImageDisplayRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var item: TestItem
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> TestImageDisplay {
        return TestImageDisplay(item: item)
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: TestImageDisplay, context: Context) {
        uiViewController.item = item
    }
}



Please check this for List vs LazyStack https://stackoverflow.com/a/77148905/23301405

It's not a memory leak. Rather it can be called the property of LazyH/VStack. LazyV/HStack lazy loads views, but doesn't have a re-use mechanism. You can check How to lazy load views using LazyVStack and LazyHStack

@LambentLight You must have a memory leak somewhere in your code that we don't see, because I can't reproduce the described behavior.
Also note that using LazyHStack will cause you to have an extremely large amount of allocations/deallocations of the UIKit instances during scrolling, because the lazy stacks have no re-use mechanism. As usual with memory leak problems, you should use Instruments to find the cause. See here and here
